# How GCE HTTP Cross-Region Load Balancing implemented

Tags: google-cloud-platform

As I know, for cross region load balancing, it is usually implemented as DNS-based load balancing, it assigns different IP address for different region.

However for GCE, as described at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/cross-region-example, it assgins only one IP address, then which region this IP address is assgined to? How the network traffic is forward? Will it increase the network latency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google HTTP/HTTPS load balancer does't require DNS-based load balancing. It uses a Global IP address which receives the user request. The traffic is routed internally within Google datacenter as such, incoming requests are sent to the region closet to the user with remaining capacity. The information is documented on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#load_distribution_algorithm).

Comment: What is Global IP address? My understanding is an IP address can be assigned to only one datacenter, for example may be assigned to an US datacenter. Then if a request from Asia, the request will be sent to US datacenter anyway, how it can be routed the closest region?

Comment: The global IP are different that regular IP addresses there prefix is advertised from multiple locations. The user request is ONLY routed to the instance in the closest region to the user making the request.

Comment: Is there details document of global IP? How is it different with regular IP address?